# ADB Shows "unauthorized" device, on a device with a broken screen. How do I authorize the session while "blind"?

Tags: android, usb, adb, android-debug, android-debugging

I've done a bunch of reading on this topic and I believe this is the closest you can probably get, but I don't know if it's possible to do this in fastboot mode or another mode other than normal.

`shell$ cd ~/.android/`

`shell$ adb push adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys`

This will push your key to the device, but obviously won't work while the phone is booted in Normal Mode until you grant it access. I do wonder, however, if it's possible to push this file if you put the device in Recovery Mode or Fastboot/etc? It would be a matter of remembering the key combos and timing to do this blind, but I think it might be possible. Am I wrong?

Any help is appreciated! This is for a Motorola Nexus 6 XT1103.

**Device Status: USB Debugging On. Rooted. Bootloader Unlocked. Android OS Version Not Known, Believed to be 11, but possibly 10.**

Comment: Topic is probably more appropriate on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=broken+screen+adb)

Comment: You can not access the on-device file-system other than from within the regular OS on a device that is bootloader locked.

Comment: It is not bootloader locked. I'll update my question.